# purpose of .dynsym section in executable

Tags: dll, dynamic-linking

What is the purpose of .dynsym section in executable I see that it is allocable to strip won't remove it. So, how does dynamic linker loader interprets it?

Comment: Read this: https://blogs.oracle.com/ali/entry/inside_elf_symbol_tables and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7103164/how-to-interpret-the-dynamic-symbol-table-in-an-elf-executable

Comment: This does not quite explain how it is interpreted.

Comment: "When searching for a symbol the dynamic linker looks through the dynamic symbol table .dynsym, so all symbols present there are usable by other programs (in other words: exported and in case of a library, part of the ABI)."  from here https://greek0.net/elf.html